# How hashCode() method in Object class is implemented?

Tags: java, object, hashcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the implementation of hashCode in java Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602501/whats-the-implementation-of-hashcode-in-java-object)

While I was browsing through the Object class, I found that there is only a declaration of the hashCode() method. Where is the implementation part? If there is no implementation how does the hashCode() method return me a result?

Comment: Those who wish to downvote the question, care to share an answer please. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's implemented in the native code. As for implementation, it's a bit more tricky - you can alter default implementation.  If you look at the "Open JDK" sources you will see the following options:

> -XX:hashCode=n (from 0 to 5).

- 0 – Park-Miller RNG (default)
- 1 – function of address and some global state
- 2 – const 1
- 3 – sequenatial counter
- 4 – address of an object
- 5 – thread specific xor-shift

You can find a detailed implmenetation here:  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp

Consider source code and comments of `static inline intptr_t get_next_hash()` function.

Comment: great to know...did not know if you could customize this also.

Comment: This seems to me the actual answer!!

Answer (score 7):

The `native` keyword indicates that it has been implemented in native code (the JVM).

Comment: thanks, but how and who gets this hashcode value and how is it returned? A little insight please!!

Comment: That would involve looking into the code of the JVM itself and knowing how JNI (Java Native Interface) implementations of methods are bound to their Java definitions.
I believe the actual value is not consistent among implementations of the JVM. If you need to rely on the actual value, override the method to conform to your own needs.

Comment: +1. and I don't think there is a spec regarding the actual value of the hashcode and manner of its calculation. (But of course, it needs to be internally consistent in the same way as any other hashCode).

Answer (score 5):

If you see the [declaration](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#Object.hashCode%28%29) of `hashcode`

```
public native int hashCode();
```

`native` in declaration indicates that it is implemented natively in jvm code.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the implementation part?

It's implemented by the framework already. [Please see the documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

> If there is no implementation how does the hashCode() method return me a result?

However, if you create a custom type you are responsible for generating an `int` value that is a good representation of the objects current state. [Here is a good example of that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827612/effective-java-hashcode-implementation)